# How do I configure Android Studio to show hints?

Tags: android-studio, ide, flutter

Currently learning Flutter. I was watching a video tutorial on YouTube ([MTechViral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNBuo-7zg2Q&t=679s)) and the IDE that he was using (Visual Studio Code) showed hints whenever he typed an element as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHlAq.png).

See how the IDE lists all the possible elements and then describes it?

Is it possible to configure Android Studio to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have installed the flutter and dart plugin, once installed intellisense should work off the bat. Maybe try updating android studio and reinstalling the dart and flutter plugins. CTRL + SPACE on windows and control + space on mac will display intellisense.

Good luck

Comment: I don't get it automatically, but CTRL + Space did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Anytime mate, it's weird it isn't displaying it automatically. Go to File>Invalidate Caches/ Restart > Click at Invalidate and Restart. If this fixes your issue don't forget to mark this as solved.