# How to extend the time to show hints about attributes in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to get android studio to show attribute hints longer than it usually does. The time window is too small for me to understand what it is saying.

I am using android studio version 3.5.1. I tried to extend the time the hints are shown by changing the setting for *caret blinking (ms)* option to 1000ms but that didn't do anything. The closest question I found related to this is [How do I configure Android Studio to show hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574589/how-do-i-configure-android-studio-to-show-hints)

Is there a way to do this and make the popup hints last longer?

Comment: You can hover with the mouse over it

Comment: @cutiko Yes, I am aware of that. But when I hover, the hint is shown for about 3 seconds. I want extend that time to 6-9 seconds.

Comment: Press ctrl/cmd while hovering?

Comment: @cutiko I just tried this. It didn't work.